# pointer optional argument in pari gp functions programming

Tags: pari, pari-gp

look at this example please

```
f(a,{e})={ispower(a,3,&e)}
```

i did that to store the result in e but when I in call the function as
f(27,t)
the program don't store the "3" in t
any help

Answer (score 0):

You cannot have pointer optional arguments to your own functions (at least not in version 2.11)

If you change your definition of `f` to return the value `e` by value:

```
f(a)={my(e); [ispower(a,3,&e), e]}
```

Now `f(27)` returns the array `[1, 3]`.

In the latest 2.13 there is supposed to be a way to pass parameters by reference: See https://pari.math.u-bordeaux.fr/archives/pari-announce-20/msg00006.html

However, the syntax suggests you will need to define `f(a, ~e) = ispower(a,3,&e)` and you will still need to use it as `f(a, ~t)` or perhaps `f(a, &t)` to get the value into `t`. (and to be honest, I'm not sure that will work - the purpose of the 2.13 enhancement is to allow call by reference of Maps and Lists, which in previous version were copied call by value).

Incidentally, {} do not mark a parameter as optional. All parameters are always optional. If you do not provide a value, then PARI will leave the parameter unassigned.